# How to connect a const qualified Qt-signal using the old syntax?

Tags: c++, qt5

It looks like the question is asked in the subj.

Here is an example:

```
class Sender : public QObject
{
  signals:
    sgSend(const QString&) const;
};

class Receiver : public QObject
{
  public slots:
    slReceive(const QString& value)
    { qDebug() << value; }
};
```

And if I connect them with the following line:

```
connect(sender, SIGNAL(sgSend(const QString&)), receiver, SLOT(slReceive(const QString&)));
```

my project is being built successfully, but it looks like the connection is not being established. I feel that I need to specify in some a way that the `sgSend` method is qualified with `const`, but I am not sure how to do this.

I think, if I'll use the new syntax of the `connect`, it will work. But for certain reasons, I cannot use it.

Comment: Off topic but... why can't you use the new Qt5 signal/slot syntax?

Comment: Not really a duplicate but maybe of help: [SO: Argument type for Qt signal and slot, does const reference qualifiers matters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1935147/7478597)

Comment: @G.M., because (a) my sender and receiver are in different modules (DLLs) and (b) my modules are being loaded manually (there is no DLL dependencies among projects >> linker does not "see" slots from another project >> errors during build).

Answer (score 0):

It seems, the issue was not in the incorrect signal signature. Actually, I specified incorrectly the receiver parameter in the `connect` call.

In any way, if someone will reach this page in the future, I found that the `const` qualified signal should be mentioned as if it is not:

```
connect(sender, SIGNAL(sgSend(const QString&)), receiver, SLOT(slReceive(const QString&)));
```

I.e., it doesn't matter whether the signal is declared as `const` or not -- the same (if we are talking about pre-5 Qt) syntax should be used.